# How to use I.attachFile in codeceptjs/protractor?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, codeceptjs

```
I.attachFile('input[type=file]', 'test.txt');
```

I try attachFile function in codeceptjs/protractor. I getthis error.

> TypeError: driver.execute is not a function

```
chromeDriver:2.33
selenium-standalone:3.7.1
codeceptJS:1.0.3

"output": "./e2e/codeceptjs_tests/reports",
"helpers": {
  "Protractor": {
    "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
    "driver": "hosted",
    "browser": "chrome",
    "rootElement": "body",
    "smartWait":5000,
```

[image: Error Pic]

[image: Code Scope]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Have you tried I.attachFile('input[type=file]', './test.txt');

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `I.attachFile('input[type=file]', 'lega-client/test.txt');`

Comment: Why should one do so? Can you explain your code such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is right but you have to select the button in the first parameter not the field

```
I.attachFile('button','test.txt')
```